# How can I get a specific file from hundreds of folders to move to one folder and rename it?

Tags: python

the file location is: /Users/D/Desktop/Files/1/no.h5 and its the same filename (no.h5) in the folders 1-400. I want all these files to collect in the same folder with their number as their new names.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use `glob` to find the files and then parse back to the number you want.

Comment: Is the number always the parent directory of the file found, or can there be more nesting?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a glob pattern to find the target files to do the move. The `pathlib` library provides a convenient way to manage the paths.

```
from pathlib import Path

base = Path(" /Users/D/Desktop/Files")
target_folder = Path("/some/where/else")

for target in base.glob("*/no.h5"):
    name = target.parent.name
    if name.isdigit():
        target.rename(target_folder/(name + ".h5"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `shutil` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html):

```
import shutil
```

...

```
shutil.copyfile(src_fname, os.path.join(target_dir, new_fname))
```

You can also walk through your base directory to create a list of files that need to be copied:

```
import os

dir_base = fr'\Users\D\Desktop\Files'
fname_base = 'no'
fname_suffix = 'h5'
list_files = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_base):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith(fname_base) and file.endswith(fname_suffix):
            list_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

The whole code for an example I created on my system looks like this:

```
import shutil
import os

#dir_base = fr'\Users\D\Desktop\Files' #<============ base directory for your case
dir_base = fr'./test' #<============ base dir for my example

fname_base = 'no'

#fname_suffix = 'h5' #<============ extension of your files
fname_suffix = 'txt' #<============ extension of files in my example

target_base_fname='abc'     #<============ base filename for new files in my example
target_dir = fr'./test/tgt' #<============ target dir for my example

list_files = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_base):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith(fname_base) and file.endswith(fname_suffix):
            list_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
            
for elem in list_files:
    print(f'processing: {elem}')
    this_dir_path = os.path.dirname(elem)
    this_dir_name = os.path.basename(this_dir_path)
    new_fname = target_base_fname + '_' + this_dir_name + '.' + fname_suffix
    shutil.copyfile(elem, os.path.join(target_dir, new_fname))
```

Comment: You don't need the `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(subdir, file))` part. In `os.walk`, the `files` list has already been checked.

Comment: Thank you very much @tdelaney for letting me know.  I modified the code accordingly.